# Change bootanimation in aosp code for custom rom

Tags: android, android-source, custom-rom

I have successfully compiled the aosp code for android 11, I tried to change the bootAnimation, but still I am seeing the legacy android bootAnimation on emulator after successfull build. Below are the changes I have done:

1. Created boot.zip file with store method as per all standards followed.
2. Kept that boot.zip in /system/media/boot.zip and /device/generic/x86_64
3. Change aosp_x86_64.mk file with below code: (As I choosen aosp_x86_64 target in lunch)

   #Boot Animation

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += 
device/generic/x86_64/boot.zip:system/media/boot.zip

```
PRODUCT_ARTIFACT_PATH_REQUIREMENT_ALLOWED_LIST += \
    system/media/boot.zip \
```

After these changes when emulator boots legacy android boot animation shown, with fluctuation of white screen after that instead of mine boot.zip contents.

Please suggest me any solution regarding the same, Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the bootanimation to the build, try to test the file via adb first. (given that your build variant is userdebug or eng)

```
adb root; adb disable-verity; adb reboot;

adb root; adb remount; adb push file.zip /system/media/bootanimation.zip

adb reboot;
```

Once you see the bootanimation in place, you can add it to the build.
I think you are using the wrong file name (check official documentation here).
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r1:frameworks/base/cmds/bootanimation/FORMAT.md

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the boot.zip file to bootanimation.zip

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
device/generic/x86_64/boot.zip:system/media/bootanimation.zip
```